# Return rows where a column value appears more than once for each ID

Tags: sql-server, select, count, common-table-expression

dB: SQL Server 2014

I need rows where `STATUS = 'Passive'` two or more times for each `ID`

TABLE:

```
Id  |   Status  |
----|-----------|
1   |   unknown |
1   |   other   |
1   |   active  |

2   |   unknown |
2   |   other   |
2   |   passive |

3   |   passive |
3   |   active  |
3   |   passive |
```

RESULT:

```
3   |   passive |
3   |   passive |
```

TRIED:

```
;WITH Z AS
(
SELECT *, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) as Cnt
FROM TheTable
)
SELECT ID, Status
FROM Z
WHERE Cnt >= 2
AND Status = 'Passive'
```

Query above seems to work, I want to be sure it works 100% correctly.
Any Comments?

I also need more conditions for another recordset. I have a column `Banned` which cannot be `1`  and `BanReason`  which cannot be `value1`, `value2`, `value3`. Where should I put these ?

---

Post Scriptum. What if I need all rows for this ID?

```
3   |   passive |
3   |   active  |
3   |   passive |
```

Comment: For `ID=3`, `status='passive'` occurs only two times. You select records which occur 3 times, regardless of `status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your current query is already such that it potentially returns every record in the table.  You can use conditional aggregation with `SUM()` as a window function.

```
;WITH Z AS
(
    SELECT *, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Passive' AND
                      Banned <> 1 AND
                      BanReason NOT IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Cnt
    FROM TheTable
)
SELECT ID, Status
FROM Z
WHERE Cnt >= 2
```

My updated answer now counts a role only if the following conditions are true:

- The status is `Passive`
- The `Banned` field is not `1`
- The `BanReason` is not `value1`, `value2`, or `value3`

If any of these conditions should fail, for any record, then it would be counted.

Comment: This seems to works. But, I corrected the question. Last row in my query must be: `AND Status = 'Passive'`

Comment: I just realized I need more conditions. I have a column `Banned` which cannot be `1`  and `BanReason`  which cannot be `value1`, `value2`, `value3`. Where should I put these ?

Comment: So you want to count records for which the status is `Passive`, the `Banned` is not `1`, and `BanReason` is not any of those 3 values?  Is that right?

Comment: Exactly. And `Passive` still occurs 2 or more times

Comment: You didn't entirely answer my question.  Do you count a row _only_ if all these new conditions are true _and_ the status is `Passive`, or something else?

Comment: Row counts when any of conditions: `the Banned is not 1, and BanReason is not any of 3 values` AND `Passive occurs twice or more for same Id`